# How to convert arrayOfObject to arrayOfArray transposing in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have arrayOfObject like below

```
[{A:100,B:300,C:200},{A:200,B:400,C:100},{A:400,B:500,C:200}]
```

and want to convert to below data structure.

```
[[A,100,200,400],[B,300,400,500],[C,200,100,200]]
```

Could anyone tell me how to do this data conversion?

Comment: Why is this related with underscore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to create one object and then get its values with `Object.values` to get array of arrays.

```js
const data = [{A:100,B:300,C:200},{A:200,B:400,C:100},{A:400,B:500,C:200}];
const result = data.reduce((r, e) => {
  Object.keys(e).forEach(key => {
    if (!r[key]) r[key] = [key]
    r[key].push(e[key])
  })
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(result))
```

Answer (score 2):

If all objects have the same keys, you can map them (seems better for tabular format):

```js
var a = [{A:100,B:300,C:200},{A:200,B:400,C:100},{A:400,B:500,C:200}]

a = Object.keys(a[0]).map(k => [k, ...a.map(o => o[k])])

console.log( a )
```